# Upload file with connect-form

Tags: javascript, node.js, upload, express

I tried to upload file with `connect-form`, but if i want to upload i must disable `bodyParser()` in `app.js`, if i keep `bodyParser()` it will have error : `loading forever`

This is my `app.js`:

```
    app.configure(function(){
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set('view option', { layout: false });

//  app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(require('stylus').middleware({ src: __dirname + '/public' }));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({secret: 'secrect', store: MemStore({
reapInterval: 60000 * 10
})}));
app.use(app.router);
});
```

This is code i call `upload file`

```
app.post('/album/upload', function( req, res) {
    req.form.complete(function(err, fields, files) {
    if (err) { next(err); console.log('error upload') }
        else {
            console.log(fields);
            console.log('---------------');
            console.log(files);
        res.send('upload successfull');
        }
     });
});
```

So, how can i do to disable `bodyParser()` when i call upload file, or anyway to help me upload file don't get error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

- Express is based on connect.
- bodyParser is based on formidable, and connect-form is based on formidable.

Having bodyParser and connect-form is like parsing the body of a request twice, but the second time around, the network stream is empty, will be unable to parse anything, waiting forever for input.

This problem has risen when connect 2.0 was released, with extended capabilities of handling multi-part requests, making connect-form obsolete.

Files should be uploaded anyway with just bodyParser, and be stored in **req.files**

Take a look at: 
https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/middleware/multipart.js (This is what express is doing with bodyParser when it encounters a multi-part request.)